# Batcher using Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

What do you think?  In particular, I'm not sure about my exception handling approach to raise errors when posting objects; but I couldn't come up with anything better.

```
public class Thing
{
    public Thing(int number)
    {
        Number = number;
    }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var thingBatcher = new Batcher<Thing>(ProcessBatch, 100, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                thingBatcher.Post(new Thing(i));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here:" + ex.Message);                
            throw;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ProcessBatch(IEnumerable<Thing> things)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Batch found: " + things.Count());


        if (things.Any(thing => thing.Number == 400))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Something bad happened");
        }
    }
}

public class Batcher<T>
{
    private BufferBlock<T> _buffer;

    private ActionBlock<IEnumerable<T>> _actionBlock;

    public Batcher(
        Action<IEnumerable<T>> processBatch,
        int batchSize,
        TimeSpan maxTimeWaitingForBatch)
    {
        Initialize(batchSize, processBatch, maxTimeWaitingForBatch);
    }

    private void Initialize(int batchSize, 
        Action<IEnumerable<T>> processBatch,
        TimeSpan maxTimeWaitingForBatch)
    {
        _buffer = new BufferBlock<T>();

        var batchStockEvents = new BatchBlock<T>(batchSize);

        // Use a timer to make sure that items do not remain in memory for too long
        var triggerBatchTimer = new Timer(delegate { batchStockEvents.TriggerBatch(); });

        // Use a transform block to reset the timer whenever an item is inserted to avoid unnessary batches
        var timeoutBlock = new TransformBlock<T, T>((value) =>
        {
            triggerBatchTimer.Change(maxTimeWaitingForBatch, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
            return value;
        });

        _actionBlock = new ActionBlock<IEnumerable<T>>(processBatch); 

        _buffer.LinkTo(timeoutBlock);
        timeoutBlock.LinkTo(batchStockEvents);
        batchStockEvents.LinkTo(_actionBlock);

        _actionBlock.Completion.ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            // todo log exception here
            Console.WriteLine(x.Exception.Message);

        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }

    public void Post(T someObject)
    {
        if (_actionBlock.Completion.IsCompleted)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The batcher is not accepting new objects as it is in a failed state");    
        }

        _buffer.Post(someObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var batchStockEvents = new BatchBlock<T>(batchSize);
```

I think that `batchStockEvents` is a weird name for a `BatchBlock`. It sounds like it's a collection of events, or something like that.

---

```
new Timer(delegate { batchStockEvents.TriggerBatch(); });
```

While using `delegate` this way allows you to ignore the parameter, I think it's cleaner (and shorter) to use lambda and use `_` as the parameter name to indicate it's ignored:

```
new Timer(_ => batchStockEvents.TriggerBatch());
```

---

```
// Use a transform block to reset the timer whenever an item is inserted to avoid unnessary batches
```

Wouldn't it be enough to reset the timer whenever a batch is triggered? It would be more efficient and you would have one less block.

Also, the comment has a typo, it should be "unnecessary".

---

What's the purpose of the `_buffer` block? Couldn't `Post()` post directly to `timeoutBlock`?

---

> In particular, I'm not sure about my exception handling approach to raise errors when posting objects; but I couldn't come up with anything better.

Yeah, you can't rely on that check in `Post()` because by the time the failure happens, all items could have been posted. But if you just want to stop doing useless work by trying to `Post()` items that can never be processed, then I think this is the right approach.